# Siamese Twin primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Can someone edit my answer to this question whether I am answering the question or I am not? The question is

> Let us say that two prime numbers $p$ and $q$ are siamese twins if $|p-q|=1$. List all the siamese twins that exist, and prove your list is complete.

#### My answer

For two prime numbers $p$ and $q$ are siamese twins if $|p-q|=1$. Assume, at least one in $p$ or $q$ is an even number. That even number is $2$. We, then let $q=2$. Therefore $|p-q|=1$, $p=1+q$, $p=1+2$, $p=3$.
Thus there is only $2$ and $3$ siamese twin existed.

Please I really need to know if I am answering what is asked in the question or not.

Comment: The question seems a little silly, but you're right.

Comment: Well, actually when you look at $|p-q|$ there are two possibilities for $p$, viz. $p=q-1$ and $p=q+1$.  The case you haven't treated is that $p=1$, but 1 is excluded from the list of primes by definition.

Comment: With the condition |p+q|=1, exactly one of the two is even and the other is odd. Having known that no even number is odd but 2, 2 and 3 form the only solution of the problem.

Comment: @Gaurav "No even number is odd but $2$"?

Comment: Correction : No even number is prime but 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct but your explanation is flawed.  You should not *assume* that one of $p$ or $q$ is even, since this is a necessary intermediate conclusion: instead argue that one of them *is* even, because they differ by $1$, and that one must equal $2$ because it is the only even prime.

Comment: can you help me with arguing that one of them is even because they are differ by 1? I don't know how to prove my argument.

Comment: What definitions or assumptions are you working with?

Comment: How about this answer. Suppose that one of p or q is even. By definition of siamese prime , p and q should be differed by 1 such that |p-q|=1. Then p or q is equal to 2 because it is the only even prime.We, then let q=2. Therefore|p-q|=1, p=1+q, p=1+2, p=3. Thus there is only 2 and 3 siamese twin existed.

Comment: That looks fine.  You can use the phrase or acronym [WLOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) to explain away the symmetry.